# Selenium WebDriver : Verify Print Window text

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have a scenario to verify Print Properties dialog opening up correctly after clicking on Print button. Aware of Robot utility class in Java which can emulate keyboard events like Escape/Enter etc. to operate on that window.

Is there any way we can verify the new dialog opened up is a Print dialog - something to verify dialog title i.e. Print or retrieve text from that windows dialog or something else which will confirm dialog to be a Print dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an image based automation tool. I use SIKULI which is based on JAVA Robot class. http://www.sikuli.org/

In SIKULI, you have to take the screenshot of the pop up or its title and then use it for comparison. SIKULI is available as a JAVA API and can be integrated with Selenium. SIKULI also procides a optical image recognition feature using tesseract. This can also be used to verify the title of the popup.

Hope this helps you.